# Show that Brownian motion on the unit circle is exponentially ergodic and has the uniform measure as its invariant distribution.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, markov-process, ergodic-theory

My search results keep bring up planar Brownian motion on the unit disk. However, I am specifically referring to

$e^{jW_{t}} = [\cos(W_t),\sin(W_t)]^{T}$

where $W_t$ is Brownian motion.
I am at a loss here, so any advice to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

**1. The uniform distribution is invariant**

Let $\theta_0$ have a uniform distribution in the circle, so that its pdf is $f(\theta)= \frac 1{2\pi}$ for $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ and $0$ otherwise.

If $\theta_0$ moves according to the law of Brownian motion during a time interval $[0,t]$, then its new distribution over the reals can be calculated by applying the Brownian transition function to the initial density $f$.

Note that arguments $\theta$ and $\theta + 2k\pi$ represent the same point in the circle, so in order to get the probability density $f_t$ over the circle their probability densities should be added . If we write $p_t(x,y)$ for the standard Brownian transition density 
$$p_t(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{(y-x)^2}{2t}}$$
 between reals $x$ and $y$, then the density $q_t(\phi, \theta)$ between points in the circle would read $$q_t(\phi, \theta) = 
\cases{
    \sum_{k\in\mathbb Z} p_t(\phi, \theta + 2k\pi) & \text{if $\phi, \theta\in [0,2\pi]$,} \\ 
    0 & \text{otherwise.}
    }$$

Using this new transition density, the distribution of the point at time $t$ is
$$\begin{align}
f_t(\theta) 
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi}q_t(\phi,\theta)f(\phi) \, d\phi\\
&= \sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\int_{0}^{2\pi}p_t(\phi,\theta + 2k\pi)f(\phi) \, d\phi\\ 
&= \sum_{k\in\mathbb Z} \int_{0}^{2\pi} p_t(\phi - 2k\pi,\theta) \frac 1{2\pi} \, d\phi\\
&= \frac 1{2\pi}\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z} \int_{-2k\pi}^{-2(k-1)\pi} p_t(\phi,\theta) \, d\phi\\
&= \frac 1{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p_t(\phi,\theta) \, d\phi = \frac 1{2\pi} = f(\theta).\\
\end{align}$$
(Changes in the order of summation are justified by the monotone convergence theorem, as the quantities are positive.)

In other words, the distribution doesn't change, as we wished to show.

**2. Exponential ergodicity**

Now we want to establish the exponential ergodicity of Brownian motion in the circle towards the uniform distribution. Writing $Q^t(x,A)$ for its transition function and $\mu$ for the uniform probability measure, this means that$^1$  $$\sup_{A\in\mathcal B[0,2\pi]}|Q^t(x,A)-\mu(A)| \le M(x)\rho^{t} $$ for some positive $\rho < 1$, finite $M(x)$. Here I used the definition of the [total variation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures) between probability measures.

We will actually prove that the pdf of $\theta_t = W_t \bmod 2\pi$ converges to the pdf of the uniform distribution over time. Indeed, the probability density of $\theta_t$ starting at $0$ is

\begin{align}
g_t(\phi)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z} p_t(0,\phi+2k\pi)
&= \sum_{k\in \mathbb Z} \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac 1{2t}(\phi+2k\pi)^2}\\
&= \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\phi^2/2t}\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z} e^{-2k\pi\phi/t}e^{ -2k^2\pi^2/t}.
\end{align}

We want to know the limit of this last expression as $t\to\infty$. Note that the terms of the series approach $1$ and it's difficult to see clearly how that compares to the decreasing factor outside the sum. Still, following the approach in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/434754/123170), we can express it in terms of Jacobi's theta function $$\vartheta_3(z,q) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}q^{k^2}e^{2kiz}$$ and apply Jacobi's imaginary transformation (more on that below) to get a more tractable expression.

Applying the transformation involves introducing a new variable $\tau$ defined by $q=e^{i\pi\tau}$. The same function expressed in terms of this variable reads $$\vartheta_3(z\mid \tau) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}e^{i\pi\tau k^2}e^{2kiz}.$$ In our case we have 
$$z =\frac{\phi\pi i}{t},\quad q = e^{-2\pi^2/t},\quad \tau=\frac{2\pi i}{t}$$ 
and using this notation our expression becomes
$$g_t(\phi) = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\phi^2/2t} \vartheta_3(z\mid \tau).$$
Now we can apply the imaginary transformation $(6)$ in [this link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobisImaginaryTransformation.html), and get the equivalent form
$$\frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\phi^2/2t} \sqrt{\frac{t}{2\pi}} e^{-iz^2/\tau\pi} \vartheta_3\Bigr(-\frac{z}{\tau} \Bigr | \Bigl. -\frac{1}{\tau}\Bigl) = \frac 1{2\pi} \vartheta_3\Bigr(-\frac{\phi}{2} \Bigr | \Bigl. \frac{it}{2\pi}\Bigl) =  \frac 1{2\pi} \vartheta_3(z', q'),$$

with $z' = -\phi/2,\,\, q'= e^{-t/2}$. Finally, notice that $q'$ approaches $ 0$ as $t\to\infty$, therefore only the constant term survives in the series $\vartheta_3(z', q')$. Thus, we have pointwise convergence of the density $g_t(\phi) \rightarrow \frac 1{2\pi}=f(\theta)$ for all $\phi\in[0,2\pi]$. Note that the same argument holds for the process started at another point $\theta_0$ if we replace $\phi$ by  $\phi-\theta_0 $.

This establishes convergence in distribution of the Brownian motion on the circle to the uniform distribution. Moreover,for any borel subset $A$ of $[0,2\pi]$ we have

$$|Q^t(\theta_0,A)-\mu(A)| 
= \left |\int_A Q^t(\theta_0, d\phi) -\int_A f(\theta)\,d\phi\right| 
\le  \int_A |g_t(\phi-\theta_0)- f(\theta)|\,d\phi $$

$$= \int_A \frac 1{2\pi}|\vartheta_3(z', q')- 1|\,d\phi 
= \int_A \frac 1{2\pi}\left|\sum_{k\ne 0}e^{-tk^2/2} e^{-ki(\phi-\theta_0)}\right|\,d\phi
\le \int_A \frac 1{2\pi}\sum_{k\ne 0 }e^{-tk^2/2}\,d\phi$$
$$ \le 2\sum_{k\ge 1}e^{-tk^2/2} \le 2\sum_{k\ge 1}e^{-tk/2} = 2\frac{e^{-t/2}}{1-e^{-t/2}} \le 4e^{-t/2} $$

for $t\ge \log 4$, so that the process is exponentially ergodic with $M=4, \rho=e^{-1/2}$, as we wished to show.

---

1. Ergodicity definition taken from [this article](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176987798)

Comment: Does someone know a "more probabilistic" proof of this fact?